Struggling to Dynamically Retrieve Post ID for ACF Query in WordPress Child Theme
I'm currently immersing myself in PHP and WordPress for a project that utilizes WPBakery and a premium theme. To customize it to my needs, I've delved into creating a child theme and successfully located and duplicated the template file I need to modify. It's been an enlightening journey of exploration and learning thus far. However, I've encountered a challenge that has become quite perplexing.
My objective is to retrieve a boolean value associated with each dynamically rendered image using Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) and apply a specific style if it's true. However, obtaining the necessary post ID has proven elusive through conventional means I've explored online. The workaround I've found involves extracting the post ID from the image URL using the $post_id = attachment_url_to_postid($image_url); function.
While this method works perfectly when manually inputting a URL copied from the GUID column in my database, it fails to function dynamically. The only way I can access the URL is through the template {{ post_full_image_url }}, as the variable $post_full_image_url remains empty. I suspect the template is populated during rendering, making it impossible to extract a string from it. Additionally, even if I manage to obtain the string, I still need to downgrade from HTTPS to HTTP for the query.
Despite my efforts, I'm at a loss. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!
vc-gitem-zone.php

<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    die( '-1' );
}
/**
 * Shortcode attributes
 * @var $atts
 * @var $el_class
 * @var $css
 * @var $position
 * @var $bgimage
 * @var $height
 * @var $link
 * @var $url
 * @var $height_mode
 * @var $featured_image
 * @var $img_size
 * @var $render
 * @var $content - shortcode content
 * Shortcode class
 * @var WPBakeryShortCode_Vc_Gitem_Zone $this
 */
$el_class = $css = $position = $bgimage = $height = $link = $url = $height_mode = $featured_image = $img_size = $render = $rel = '';

$css_style = $css_style_mini = '';
$image_block = $image = '';

$atts = vc_map_get_attributes( $this->getShortcode(), $atts );
extract( $atts );


//echo '{{ post_full_image_url }}';
// this will render the url, but my best guess is that this placeholder is filled on render therefore immmutable, 
// if I reference the actual var $post_full_image_url nothing will happen $image_test_url will remain empty
$image_test_url = '{{ post_full_image_url }}';

echo $image_test_url;

$post_id = attachment_url_to_postid( str_replace("https://", "http://", $image_test_url));

echo $post_id;

// Retrieve ACF field value
$lent = get_field('is_lent', $post_id);

if (empty($lent)) {
    echo "<script>console.log('ACF field \"is_lent\" is empty or not defined for post ID: " . $post_id . "');</script>";
} else {
  echo "<script>console.log('ACF field \"is_lent\": " . json_encode($lent) . "');</script>";
};

// more code that assambles the html


How is convertUrl() invoked?  Is it attached to a WordPress hook?

I updated the question, and I guess now it how do i get the damn post_id for every time this template file is rendered .

<script>console.log('ACF field... writes a message to the browser console.  But you're using it inside PHP which is executed on the server.  Don't you really want to use error_log() at this point?  It's hard to tell because it's not clear what triggers the above code to execute.  WPBakery (according to Google) is a page builder.  It looks like your code above is related to a shortcode.  It's just not clear what context your code executes in.  What triggers your code to execute?

If this is truly a shortcode in the sense of a WordPress shortcode, then you can't echo output in the shortcode function.  See last paragraph of this section... https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/#more-information

Thank you for your comments; as I'm new to wp/php, I'm figuring things out by the minute. I now realize that my question is a different one. I will rephrase and post a new question.

Not sure if it applies, but the post ID is only going to be available after "INIT" hook. might actually be a later hook like "WP"
